# Obtain Inner JSON Array Values

Tags: java, arrays, json, dictionary, dart

I'm attempting to get the values for the "filterInputParameters" array within the serviceResponseValue map.  Right now I have attempted to iterate through the map but could only obtain the first level of data such as the displayName and I need to go one-two levels deeper for the values in filterInputParamters array.  Please let me know if you need more information.

Dart Code:

```
var jsonString = response;

   var dropDown = querySelector("#asset");

   Map jsonObject = JSON.decode(jsonString) as Map;
       dropDownList = jsonObject["serviceResponseValue"] as List<Map>;

   LinkedHashMap<String, Map> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map>();

//the one causing issues and returning null
     var ddValues2 = dropDownList
       //extract the 'displayValue'
       .map((e2) => e2['filterInputParameters']['value']);
       //create a set to eliminate duplicates
       //.toSet().toList()
       //sort the result 
       //..sort();

       ddValues2.forEach((e2) {
         print(e2);

       });
```

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn, and then things will make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dart
Map jsonObject = JSON.decode(jsonString) as Map;
print(jsonObject["serviceResponseValue"][0]["filterInputParameters"]);
```

In JSON `[` `]` indicate a List and `{` `}` a Map.
You access a list element by passing a numeric index (`xxx[5]` to get the 6th item)
and a String to access a Map item (`xxx["serviceResponeValue"]`).

Your JSON starts with

```dart
 {  // the outer element is a map
   "serviceResponseValue":[  // this map item can be accessed with a 
                             // string index"serviceResponseValue"
                             // after the colon `:` starts the associated value, a list
                             // the first item can be accessed using [0]
      {  // which contains a map
```

...

```dart
       "filterInputParameters":[  // this item of the map is returned by ["filterInputParameters"]
          {  
             "id":"8a4984e047d0e40d0147d0e410020008",
```

Comment: Question, how would I get the second map of values where it says 48 hours, etc.?  I tried jsonObject["serviceResponseValue"][2]["filterInputParameters"]; without luck.

Comment: `jsonObject["serviceResponseValue"][1]`