# Dart Future Value Request Incompatible

Tags: java, json, http, indexing, dart

I'm attempting to obtain a JSON feed from a URL, which is working fine except that when I attempt to pass the feed data (jsonString) into the jsonObject Map with JSON.decode(jsonString), I get an error saying that "the argument type Future cannot be assigned to a parameter type String."  The problem is I'm trying to make this server request within a button click to load the proper value for the timestamp needed in a previous question I had here: [Obtain Inner JSON Array Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310276/obtain-inner-json-array-values).  I need similar functionality in the button click.  The currentIndex integer is the position of the HTML Drop-Down.  Please let me know if you need more information.

Dart Code:

```
@observable int currentIndex = 0;

  dropDownURL = "http://url";
      print(dropDownURL);

 var request = HttpRequest.getString(dropDownURL);
          request.catchError(handleFailure);


  var jsonString = request;
    print(jsonString);

  Map jsonObject = JSON.decode(jsonString) as Map;

  startDate.value = jsonObject["serviceResponseValue"][currentIndex]["filterInputParameters"][currentIndex]["value"];

  print(jsonObject["serviceResponseValue"][currentIndex]["filterInputParameters"][currentIndex]["value"]);

  print(startDate.value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to leave therefore a short answer

This line doesn't work

```
var jsonString = request;
```

look for `[Dart] HttpRequest` here on the list and you will find a lot of examples.